# How do I color just the outer union of two concentric circles in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

I'm looking to add a separate fill to the areas labeled "Color" in the diagram below. I'm using Sketch 3.

The concentric circles were both created by subtracting two concentric circles from each other.

Please let me know if this is enough information to move forward, as this is my first time posting.

[image: Areas that need different fill]

Answer (score 1):

1. Make upper oval with desired border width and color. Fill it with the desired upper area color.
2. Duplicate that oval and fill it with the desired lower area color.
3. Place second oval over first one with the desired margin from top.
4. Select both ovals and duplicate them.
5. With the two new created ovals selected press <kbd>Intersect</kbd> button, this action will create new shape, so you can fill it with desired background color.

That's the simple way to solve your problem!
[image]